# Regex Match to string for Screenconnect

Tags: regex

I am having issues matching regex to pull the follow out of the text below.

```
23d63443-47d5-4b19-9fce-5a0b151526a0
```

Output will always look like below but what I'm looking to match above varies slightly.

> `"C:\Program Files\ScreenConnect Client (bd5ecacad274bdc6)\Elsinore.ScreenConnect.ClientService.exe" "?e=Access&y=Guest&h=screenconnect.com&p=8041&s=23d63443-47d5-4b19-9fce-5a0b151526a0&k=BgIAAACkAABSU0ExAAgAAAEAAQDvDCdQGcu%2fuKP5cPvdclGMBYhhdI0zIC3oNwkJnNmUCbrd%2bAgugzNThBGHoR8mu30zR6nYVJbqYrtjMgxvhC7b2MJptUanf5mLh%2fMpmdQE1rGMtTqCWDH%2fpXQa4DN5QUbz66UcJ%2bdpCQ5TUax8oSw%2fX1I2x1llgax4jCk%2fWc6%2fpcj3JQIODej0z85X%2f1LJhELki2eNcD1QMMN0t%2fR7GZICw7HlL%2ftqOnZyF%2fnr9d62LQQ37n4L5Ra9S5VDk1B9V8umOx9aTkeXuhcRE88e6uGXkuNSQfXjqaAlwSV1xNkPJA8aJvS%2bkkMSNCWfi5chKhGyU4CXaldWPDcsPpA05XKw&t=&c=&c=&c=&c=&c=&c=&c=&c="`

How to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following regex to capture what you want:

```
&s=([^&]+)&
```

`&s=` matches the literal characters `&s=`, `[^&]+` (a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)) matches any character other than `&` one or more times. It is enclosed in a pair of parentheses (a [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html)), meaning the matched text is captured to group 1 (as it's the first pair of parentheses in the regex).

**Visualization:**

[image]

Group 1 will contain the string you're looking for.

[**RegEx Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/kS3gM6/1)